# How many connections should I open to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

If I using in my app for example -  3 databases, should i need to open connection for each one, or one connection for all?

I using mongodb driver in nodejs.

Comment: Its 3 databases in one cluster or all in the different cluster?

Comment: the same cluster.

Comment: here's way to do it using mongoose
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/3.8-Release-Notes#connection-pool-sharing